# ubuntu software center not opening in 12.10

Tags: software-center

I am trying to open ubuntu software center using the command line by typing software-center and i get the following

```
2013-02-10 12:09:54,006 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-02-10 12:09:54,013 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-02-10 12:09:54,115 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py', 410, '_introspect_error_handler')'
2013-02-10 12:09:54,115 - dbus.proxies - ERROR - Introspect error on com.ubuntu.sso:/com/ubuntu/sso/credentials: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/lib/ubuntu-sso-client/ubuntu-sso-login exited with status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 337, in __init__
    self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/appmanager.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.oauth_token = helper.find_oauth_token_sync()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/ubuntusso.py", line 139, in find_oauth_token_sync
    sso.find_credentials()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/login_impl/login_sso.py", line 75, in find_credentials
    self.proxy.find_credentials(self.appname, self._get_params())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/lib/ubuntu-sso-client/ubuntu-sso-login exited with status 1
```

What should be done? I tried to open it otherwise but with no results.

Comment: Can you check the output for sudo apt-get install -f?

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed a Zope module from some other source than the official repository, to fix this run the following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope
sudo ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/zope/interface/
```

**Source:** https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1085425

Comment: i dont have zope installed

Comment: So, it's working now?

Comment: no it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a secondary display/monitor?  If so, turn it on -- the update center is probably on your extended workspace.  Otherwise, check your display settings to see if you have a "pseudo" extended display that all of your windows are hiding in.

Comment: I have the same issue as OP and when I view my displays config, I only have one display. I do have virtual workspaces enabled, but it's not open on any of them. When I search for a `software-center` process, there isn't any running.